# Unable to install intervention/image library

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i run the command

```
composer require intervention/image
```

but i get an error

> composer require intervention/image Using version ^2.5 for
>   intervention/image ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer
>   repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including
>   require-dev)
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "https://packagist.org/p/symfony/error-renderer%24a4fceda433a325bdc189d13359dfd06610c76c180a04772344bbc0402e06b
>   3dc.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your composer cache, run following in your command line:

`composer clear-cache`